# цепочка вызовов в сокращенном виде

Tags: javascript, jquery

доброго времени суток, есть куча кода с повторяющимися цепочками вызовов, есть ли какие нибудь способы сократить код подобным образом: `.slideUp().slideDown().slideUp()` в `.custSlide()` , при этом без функций (не будет возможности продолжить цепочку), и при этом в рамках текущего js файла?

Comment: ничего не понятно, что ты в итоге хочешь получить

Comment: в итоге я хочу получить вместо 3х вызовов в цепочке один, который вызовет внутри себя те самые 3

Comment: я конкретно про вот эту часть: _при этом без функций (не будет возможности продолжить цепочку), и при этом в рамках текущего js файла?_ - с вызовом все просто: пишешь функцию, в которой вызываешь указанные три, если хочешь, можешь ее даже в fn запихать и вызывать через точку

Comment: спасибо за мысли, ответ ниже - именно то что я хотел, про "без функции" написал от непонимания сути решения проблемы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

```
$.fn.custSlide = function() {
    return this.slideUp().slideDown().slideUp();
}
```

Comment: тогда уж сразу надо было return делать